spinlock why do some projects loop 30 times _mm_pause()?
eg: golang runtime spinlock,  if atomic.cas fail, loop 30 times _mm_pause()
for i := 0; i < spin; i++ {
    for l.key == mutex_unlocked/*0*/ {
       if atomic.Cas(key32(&l.key), mutex_unlocked, wait) {
          return
       }
    }
    //this is: for(i:=0;i<30;i++) _mm_pause();  
    procyield(active_spin_cnt)  
}

qs:
1. I don't understand why execute _mm_pause 30 times. What exactly is the CPU doing during these 30 times? Essentially, is it just idling? The core purpose is to sleep for a few instruction cycles?  My confusion is why it is 30 instead of 1.
2. Is the following spinlock implementation reasonable?
inline void cpu_pause(){
    _mm_pause();
}

template<u16 Times>
inline void cpu_pauses(){
    for (int i = 0; i < Times; ++i) cpu_pause();
}

struct Spinlock: $nocopy{
public:
    std::atomic_flag m_flag;
public:
    async<void> lock(){
       again;
       //  fast path; 
       if(!m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) co_return;
       if(!m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) co_return;
       
       cpu_pauses<1>();
       if(!m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) co_return;
       
       cpu_pauses<3>();
       if(!m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) co_return;
       
       cpu_pauses<5>();
       if(!m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) co_return;
       
       // This is a coroutine yield point, which allows the thread to temporarily suspend the current task, execute the next task, and then resume execution at a later time
       co_await Yield{};
       goto again;
    }
    

What exactly is the CPU doing during these 30 times?

std::atomic_flag, async<void>,  co_await Yield{} are not valid C. Why do you tag it with C?

Does this answer your question? What is the purpose of the "PAUSE" instruction in x86?
